# Does Prism provide a way to cancel navigation TO a view?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I would like to be able to block a navigation to a certain view with a password i.e. when a user wants to navigate to that view, a dialog appears and he has to type in the password first. 
The `IConfirmNavigationRequest` interface provides a way to confirm navigation from the view/VM but not TO the view/VM.
Is it possible to implement this using Prism?

Answer (score 1):

IConfirmNavigation does prevent navigation TO another view is the result is false.  Just check if the user is logged in, and if they aren't then show/navigate to a login screen, otherwise navigate to your target view.  Another optin is in the OnNaviatedTo of the target is to check, and if they aren't logged in show your dialog to log them in.

Answer (score 0):

You could navigate to the login screen instead, and that in turn will navigate to the final target (which it receives as a navigation parameter) upon successful login.